# Pandoc produces error from .tex to .docx on redefinition of \part

Tags: latex, pandoc

On using pandoc to convert a LaTeX file to a Word document I ran into the following error:

```
...>pandoc test.tex -o test.docx  --pdf-engine=xelatex

    Error at "source" (line 12, column 1):
    unexpected \part
    expecting \end{document}
    \part{Introduction}
    ^
```

The error occurs also with `pandoc test.tex -o test.docx`. Here is a minimal example that compiles with XeLaTeX but produces the error in pandoc :

```
%test.tex
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand*\parttitle{}\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{\ifx\\#1\\%
      \origpart{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
   \else
      \origpart[#1]{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Context}
\section{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\part` comes from  [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13392/44805) on Tex SE. On the other hand using the answer chosen by the OP, pandoc doesn't complain:

```
%test.tex
\documentclass{book}
\let\Oldpart\part
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Context}
\section{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{document}
```

What difference causes the error in the first ?

Comment: Probably a bug or oversight in the pandoc latex reader. Note though that LaTeX can be pretty complex, so you'll always be able to write some weird, complicated LaTeX that pandoc doesn't parse successfully. Pandoc's markdown though, corresponds more or less one-to-one to its internal document AST. Since you've already found a workaround, not sure what to answer...

Comment: @mb21 Indeed, that makes sense. I wondered if there were known commands that tend to generate incompatibilities with Pandoc. But I guess that's hard to say...

Comment: if you think it's a common enough command/pattern you can report it to the pandoc issue tracker, or otherwise ask on pandoc-discuss first.